# Respawned Prefab instance doesnt destroy on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been up with Unity2D for like 3 days or so and I have been getting an issue with destroying a respawned Prefab instance.

Here is an [example](https://gyazo.com/771528a5b44ec50e7b1360d07ffd1bb0) of what the issue looks like

Below is my current code

```cs
    public GameObject effect;
    public GameObject objj;
    public Transform pl;
    void Start()
    {

        Instantiate(objj, new Vector3(0, 3, -1), Quaternion.identity);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * speed));
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Instantiate(effect, pl.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(objj, new Vector3(0, 3, -1), Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
    }
```

There has been no errors in the console

**EDIT**

Based on the comments i would like to clarify:

1) pl is the player's Transform(used for getting coordinates to initiate a death effect)

2) objj is the player's game object(using it to instantiate the player gameobject after collision)

3) sphere does have the player tag, otherwise it wouldnt have respawned the first time

**ALSO**

I know i can disable the component or change its coordinates to spawn but it would be better if i could know how to reinstantiate the object with this issue fixed

**MY QUESTION**

Why doesnt the player's prefab instance destroy again after the first player instance destroyed and respawned?

Comment: Why do you instantiate your objj again when colliding with the player? What is your question? Why the player is not destroyed on the second contact? Is the respawned player tagged with "Player"?

Comment: Does objj have the tag `Player`?

Comment: As something of a side note, I would suggest that if you're just respawning the player any time the player dies, you should just change the position of the transform (and set the GameObject inactive or disable the renderer if you want it to briefly disappear). Needlessly repeated Instantiate and Destroy calls would seem to generate lots of garbage and be generally inefficient.

Comment: @silencewebber In this specific case it applies only to one or two single objects and isn't done that often so it is ok-ish here. But ofcourse in general you are right ;)

Comment: what is the `pl` and if you use it for the effect spawn position .. why don't you sue it also for the other spawns?

Comment: @derHugo & others I have edited my question with the required details

Comment: Where are you assiging pl? Could you also share the script, that's on the Player object?

Comment: I have assigned pl to the script in the inspector and the player object doesnt have any special respawn script's set up rather than a movement one

Comment: You should reassign pl everytime you create a new player object, since the original object is already destroyed

Comment: its a prefab not directly an object, the prefab would stay assigned even after an instance of it is deleted

Comment: Yeah, but it should be the transform of the object. Try `GameObject temp = Instantiate(objj, new Vector3(0, 3, -1), Quaternion.identity);` and `pl = temp.transform`

Comment: where do you want me to replace it with? i am a bit confused sorry

Comment: do you mean [this](https://i.gyazo.com/94c199192299e2e91623c10ad13e7b3d.png) way?

Comment: Yeah and the same in Start(). Now at least your effect should be in the right position

Comment: same thing as in question, it destroys once but the second time it doesnt destroy

Comment: What still confuses me is, that in your video the first time the Player is destroyd by a trigger-Collider, but the second time, it actually collides. So maybe you should try `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead of `OnTriggerEnter2D`? Or check the `IsTrigger`-box on the collider of the gear

Comment: Is Trigger is checked, I have tried OnCollisionEnter2D before but it didnt work either. It doesnt destroy the object when i use OnCollisionEnter2D and no error pops up either

Comment: But if IsTrigger is checked how does the PlayerObject collide with the gear in your video?

Comment: it triggers after the collision?

Comment: Pause the game after second object has been spawned and inspect all objects in the scene. Are all colliders intact? Do they have the correct tags? It kinda looks like the spinning thing's trigger collider is getting destroyed? Does objj have any script on it?

Comment: Checked all the objects after pausing the game after respawn, the character still has the player tag in it.objj does only have a movement script which is not in use right now